# Magento CMS Page as Category Landing Page

Tags: magento, content-management-system, categories

I have a problem deciding how to implement my category/cms page structure in Magento. It seems so over rigid in its design, even to the extent of adding custom fields to categories, I had to access phpmyadmin and hack it manually.

Ok, so consider this basic sitemap, with page types.

```
Home                          CMS PAGE
    Shop                      Category
        Just In               Category      
        Clothes               Category
        Shoes                 Category
        Accessories           Category
        Sale                  Category
```

So Home will be a CMS page, that is ok. Just In, Clothes and all other 3rd level categories will display a list or grid of products. Easy peasy.

My issue is with Shop. I need this to contain static blocks or widgets (cannot yet see the difference), and other elements such as a daily featured product, links to promotions etc. This page will not display a list/grid of products, that is not what I need.

If I create a CMS page called Shop, there is a conflict between breadcrumbing, url titles, and a bunch of other stuff.

My question is: how do I create a category called 'Shop' and make it behave like a CMS page with blocks of manageable widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Categories`, select a category and go to the `Display Settings` tab.  Change `Display Mode` to `Static Blocks Only` and select the static block that you want to display on that page.

Another option is to use a Wordpress integration extension.  Fishpig has one available for Magento.